# Power management for components on a PCB

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb, integrated-circuit, power-management

I’m a begineer in PCB designing and I'm designing a circuit where I have 4 ICs connected in parallel. I have used JW5068A IC which have output voltage of 5 V and max current of 8 A for whole circuit.

First IC require 5 V and 1.8 A, second IC require 3.3 V and 2 A, third IC require 3.3 V and 150 mA and fourth IC require 3.3 V and 300 mA. Apart from this I have few resistors,capacitors and  inductors in circuit. I have also used 3 separate LDO for 5 V to 3.3 V for 2nd, 3rd, and 4th IC.

Now my doubt is if I should use only one output from JW5068A and connect all ICs and components in parallel or should I use IC like MMPF0100NPAEP which have several outputs?
I’m asking this because I am thinking that 5 V 8 A will require thicker/ wider tracks on layout and in general is it bad to use single power supply?

Comment: There are other converters with dual output. Can't you use one supply everthing 3.3 V?

Comment: You can wire the things in parallel that use the same voltage, but you need two converters (or a converter that outputs two voltages) to get two different voltages. You are likely to overheat or destroy the 3.3V ICs by giving them 5V.

Answer (score 0):

Use two JW5068A, one for 5V IC's and one for 3V IC's. The MMPF0100NPAEP is a little bit over engineered and very complicated to use (one day just to read the datasheet). (Unless it's intended for high volume, high quality production and big budget.)

Use relatively large capacitors (>= 100uF) before and (>10uF) after the buck converters. Larger than recommended by the producer or one recommended + one much larger. Use 1uF or 2.2uF at every ic Vcc pin (not 0.1uF).
If you use high frequencies, add +- 0.01uF in parallel with larger, reservoir, capacitors (exact value depends on frequency).

You can of course use more than two buck convertors if track width is a concern. But I don't think it should be if you use separate tracks from a single converter. If you put several high current devices along a single long zigzag'ing track, then it can be an issue. Don't do that.
You can also connect the separate tracks at some points giving several current paths.

The best is to use a dedicated layer for each supply voltage or at least for the one that will be the most solicited. And one, or even two, for ground.